# div inside form not being 'seen'

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a div inside my form which is filled with a field based on the value of the select box above it. This field always comes back as 'null' when submitted, I put a div around other parts of the form to test if it was in fact the div itself and each field with a div around it kept coming back as 'null'.

```
<form>
<span id="writenode"></span>
<input type="button" value="Add language" onClick="addlanguage()" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>

<!--This div below is called every time I want to add a new 'instance' of this form
this div works fine, its when i add a div inside that one I get 'null'-->

<div id="readnode" style="display: none">
    <select name="rank">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Rating</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
    </select>   
    <select name="time">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Time</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" value="X"
        onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" />
</div>
```

So the code above works fine its when i add a div inside i get 'null' like below;

```
<form>
<span id="writenode"></span>
<input type="button" value="Add language" onClick="addlanguage()" >
<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
</form>

<!--This div below is called every time I want to add a new 'instance' of this form
this div works fine, its when i add a div inside that one I get 'null'-->

<div id="readnode" style="display: none">
    <select name="rank">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Rating</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
    </select>   
<div id='testdiv'>
    <select name="time">
        <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Time</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="0">0</option>
    </select>
</div>
    <input type="button" value="X"
        onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" />
</div>
```

Whats my best way around this? and how would I go about doing it?

EDIT: The Div 'readnode' is called and placed inside the form when needed, replacing the div 'writenode' which is seen inside the form above. This div works perfectly fine. When i add another div (testdiv) inside the 'readnode' any fields placed inside the new div (testdiv) always come back as null when using $_get.

EDIT2:

Function that puts the readnode in place of the writenode,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*  Set the counter that will increase every time
    the user adds a new language*/
var counter = 0;
function addlanguage()
{
    // Ask the user for input
    var language = prompt("Language Name","");
    if (language == "" || language == null)
    {
        alert("Please enter a language.");
    }
    else
    {
        counter++;
        // Find the element to be copied
        var newNode = document.getElementById('readnode').cloneNode(true);
        newNode.id = '';
        newNode.style.display = 'block';
        var newField = newNode.childNodes;
        // Give all fields a unique value
        for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++)
        {
            var theName = newField[i].name;
            var theId = newField[i].id;
            if (theName)
            {
                newField[i].name = theName + counter;
            }
            if (theId == "languagename")
            {
                // Change the field to the user input
                newField[i].innerHTML = language;
            }
            if (theName == "lang")
            {
                // Replace the hidden field with the correct language
                newField[i].value = language;
            }
        }
        // Insert the elements
        var insertHere = document.getElementById('writenode');
        insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode,insertHere);
    }
}
</script>
```

and this is the php;

```
<?php
if ($_GET["time1"] == null)
{ ?>
    <form>
    <span id="writenode"></span>
    <input type="button" value="Add language" onClick="addlanguage()" >
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>
<?php
}
else
{
    $final = 0;
    $i = 1;
    while($final == 0)
    {
        $gettime = "time" . $i;
        $getRank = "rank" . $i;
        $time = $_GET[$gettime];
        $rank = $_GET[$getRank];

        if ($language == "")
        {
            $final = 1;
        }

        if ($final == 0)
        {
            // Show the user the input
            echo("<p>Your <strong>$time</strong> is <strong>$rank</strong>.</p>");
        }
        $i++;
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Is it only the one with display:none that doesn't work?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "get 'null'" where and when is this null appearing?

Comment: The DIV isn't inside the FORM, so it's not at all clear what you're talking about.

Comment: The one with display:none works fine the 'testdiv' one doesn't work, when i use a $_GET the field inside the testdiv comes back null, i remove the testdiv and th field that was inside but now isn't comes back with the right value.

Comment: Are you submitting the form with AJAX or normal form submission? Can you show the code that inserts the DIV into the form, and the submission code if any?

Comment: added the javascript and php

Answer (score 0):

When you put it inside a div, it's no longer part of newNode.childNodes, so you never get to set the name properly. You'll have to check childs of childs or use jQuery to simplify things.

```
for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++)
        {
    var subField = newField.childNodes;


    for (var i=0;i<subField.length;i++) {
            var theName = subField[i].name;
            var theId = subField[i].id;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I go about checking childs of childs or convert this over to jQuery? I have little to no experience with javascript/jQuery and this is the only part of my little project where its needed.

Comment: You should also loop newField.childNodes. jQuery automatically loop all available nodes, you'll just need to indicate the name.

Comment: How would I go about looping the newField.childNodes? Again this is pretty much the 1st javascript I've ever touched

Comment: @user2558771 I added a small example of how it could look like. There might be better way of doing this.

Comment: I have changed my original question taking into consideration your sugegstions

Comment: @user2558771 you should've asked a new question as this one is different from the original.

Comment: I would but this question and my last seem to be disliked and have gained me a question posting ban.